# Loading JS configuration from server?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, web-applications

I want my JS to load certain information that needs to come from the server. Examples would be URLs, language specific messages, etc. What is the best way to get this information from the server to the JS?

Right now, I have such values stored in an actual JS file. I don't like this approach because information is duplicated on the server side.

Would it be a good idea to have an initial JS to make an Ajax request to get all these details? Perhaps store this in a global variable so that it is accessible from anywhere? (A benefit of my current approach is that I don't need to necessarily set such information as a global variable; I could, for example, hard code and alert message where it is needed).

Any advice on best practice for my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already use PHP, why not use that to generate a dynamic .js file that contains all your variables and include that on the page?

PHP:

```
var foo = '<?php echo $foo; ?>';
var bar = '<?php echo $bar; ?>';
```

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vars.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="actual_javascript_stuff.js"></script>
...
```

This way you can keep all your config in one place. You can include the PHP's config file and populate the JavaScript variables using that.

Comment: Also you might need to add `header("content-type: application/x-javascript");` at the top of the file

Comment: Not necessarily necessary, browsers should be able to figure it out just by the `type="text/javascript"` bit. Not 100% sure of this though.

Comment: this means the JS is embedded in the HTML instead of loaded as an external file. When the user goes to another page, it means that this information would have to be downloaded again. This is not desired.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie, that was just as an example, of course you can include it as an external file also. I've updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ajax sure, but if you don't use ajax to anything else a simple solution is to add an extra `<script type="text/javascript" src="config.php"></script>` and have that file auto generate JS settings.

Comment: I suppose I could create a separate file in my application that accesses the different parts of the framework to put together what the JS needs. The problem is when something changes (e.g. language is changed), how would the JS know about that? config.php will most likely be cached and won't be re-downloaded. This means my site's language would change, but not the messages in my JS. I suppose I could put a query string after config.php to address any caching issues, but not sure if that's a good idea . . . .

Comment: You could make sure that you load the js file with a random parameter each time, ex: `<script type="text/javascript" src="config.php?<random jibberish here>"></script>`, if you change this every time the page loads, maybe insert the script tag with javascript or something lke tha, but yes, if the settings change alot ,use ajax to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file that contains all your configuration to filename.js.php, this tells the server that it needs to parse the file before it is served.

Then use php expressions to get your values, for example:

```
var username='<?=$username;?>';
```

(By the way `<?=...;?>` is the shorthand for `<?php echo $username; ?>`)

Another way of going about it, have all the properties that you want to pass to the front end in a PHP object, and pass it as a json string.

So initially, in filename.js.php, have something like:

```
var properties = <?=json_encode($php_properties_object);?>
```

Then when the language is sent on the client, simply return that same json encoded object to your front end through an AJAX query and assign it to the `properties` javascript variable. Then get the javascript code to reload all the config of off that.

Comment: @jd: The values could change at any time. For example, in the case of switching languages. When user switches languages, a flag is set in the system and the site changes languages. This config file in my application isn't actually just 1 file. It's part of a framework where configurations, languages, etc. are defined in different parts.

Comment: If you don't want to reload the whole page, then you'll have to use AJAX when there is a language change. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: http://www.gifnoc.com/config (if it does JSON I suppose)